# Kafka consumer with Flask Rest API is not listening with latest messages

Tags: python, apache-kafka

What I actually need is producer needs to send messages in an API and at that instant the consumer has to consume and display.

I have tried all the options sometimes it works and sometimes it do not work

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

def get_consumer():
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(group_id='1',
                          bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                          auto_offset_reset='latest',
                          enable_auto_commit=False,
                          consumer_timeout_ms=-1,
                          max_poll_records=100)
    consumer.subscribe('my_topic')

    for m in consumer:
        print(m.value)

app.route('/get_data',methods=["GET"])
def get_data():
    get_consumer()
```

I am writing a rest API for Kafka consumer to listen to the latest messages which it is not displaying.

Comment: Are you able to consume any message at all or nothing?

Comment: can you explain the scenarios how you tested it? For example while Producer publishing messages, does consumer is up and running?

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting to happen here... `print` doesn't return HTML data to the webpage, and this won't keep the consumer constantly running. The request will just immediately return

Comment: @ Nishu I am able to consume some messages, sometime

Comment: @Deadpool Yes the consumer is up and running while the producer is publishing messages

Comment: @cricket__007 I want to print the latest messages thats it, I am not sending them to the webpage. And the consumer is waiting for new messages at loop starting for m in consumer.

Comment: does it poll after sometime? or it doesn't poll at all? @LakshmiPrasanna

Comment: No it is not pooling at all @ Deadpool